# OWASP CheckList Web

Tags: owasp

In my company we use AppScan Enterprise (or Standard) for Dynamic Analysis to check the type of vulnerabilities on the websites under our observation but only that isn't enough.

Our programmers now need to use OWASP Checklist (ASVS 3.0) and fill the checklist. This process is in "alpha mode" and we are still learn about it.

What I noticed is that Mobile Checklist is really well configured with some sheets and testing procedure but the Web Checklist doesn't have that testing procedure.

**We are using this guide:** https://media.readthedocs.org/pdf/owasp-aasvs/latest/owasp-aasvs.pdf but we feel that's isn't enough for fill all the categories.

Can someone recommend a video with a profound explanation or some pdf's guides to complete the information we already have?

Thank you in advance.

Best Regards.

Answer (score 0):

Have you seen the owasp webpage?. Perhaps this pdf could help you futher [Owasp pdf](https://www.owasp.org/images/7/72/OWASP_Top_10-2017_%28en%29.pdf.pdf) and i would check here for more resources in general [Owasp main page](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Main_Page)

Comment: The "OWASP Top 10 - 2017" pdf has the most common vulnerabilities... Maybe, i wasn't so clear in my explanation: For example, i want to test this topic: **V9. Data Protection Verification Requirements: Verify the application has the ability to detect and alert on abnormal numbers of requests for data harvesting for an example screen scraping**. There is some guide to fill this point? Maybe some tool we need to install to do this? Can only be performed through Code Review? 

Thanks.

Comment: Im reading the contents of the v9. It is telling you some security measures, perhaps its not telling you directly how to deal with it, but it is telling you that with xss the client data can be stolen. So you should try to sanitize xss. I dont know particular tools, but if you want to check for vulnerabilities, there are some tools such as OWASP ZAP, that have a lot of test included. And perhaps the testing guide can help you further [Testing Guide](https://www.owasp.org/images/1/19/OTGv4.pdf) on how to test for xss for example

Comment: I know ZAP but I'm using instead **BurpSuite** and **AppScan Enterprise/Standard** to check for vulnerabilities and possibly false positives. We already did those tests of SQL injection, XSS attack, CSRF attacks, etc... I just want to know if there is a good guide to follow for ASVS 3.0 with the best testing procedure but thanks anyway @nalnpir.